# How to change background color when I mention color on input field and hit button

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-listener

Ok guys I have a simple `form` and `form` and it has one input field which has `id` `#input`. And I have a button which has the value of add. Now my motive is that when I type any color on `input` field and `click` the add `button` then that color should show on the background of `body`.

Comment: have you tried something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <button onclick="document.body.style['background-color'] = document.getElementById('input').value;return false;">add</button>
</form>
```

Achieving the same with event listener:

```js
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    document.body.style['background-color'] = document.getElementById('input').value;
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="input">
        <button id="mybutton" type="button">add</button>
    </form>
```